# Visual Studio cl.exe error in installing rpy2

Tags: python, django, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, rpy2

I am installing rpy2 in Django and got the following errors.

```
 C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\bin\HostX86\x64\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -I.\rpy\rinterface "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\ATLMFC\include" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.15.26726\include" /Tc.\rpy\rinterface\r_utils.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\.\rpy\rinterface\r_utils.obj
r_utils.c
.\rpy\rinterface\r_utils.c(23): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'stdlib.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\2017\\Enterprise\\VC\\Tools\\MSVC\\14.15.26726\\bin\\HostX86\\x64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2
```

Tried many solutions available in internet but none worked for me

[image: error image]

also attaching my Visual studio installations list

[image]

[image]