# Unable to install/run rpy2 in Django

Tags: django, windows, visual-studio, pip, rpy2

I am having multiple issues in Installing  rpy2 in Django. When i write

```
pip install rpy2
```

it gives me Visual studio installation errors, I have fulfilled all the requirements of visual related errors but still it remain unsolved I have mentioned it [asked here before](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51954098/visual-studio-cl-exe-error-in-installing-rpy2)

When I install rpy2 using wheel(.whl) file it gets installed but when I run my rpy2 code it gives Cstack limit error [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51798111/django-app-crashing-when-using-pandas2ri)

Is there any fix which can solve my long lasting problem??

Answer (score 0):

I am guessing that you are on Windows. The documentation does contain potentially useful information:

https://rpy2.github.io/doc/v2.9.x/html/overview.html#microsoft-s-windows-precompiled-binaries

Comment: Yes I am on Windows and I have tried these installations resulting to the VisualStudio errors that i have mentioned on the post

Comment: There is very limited support for rpy2 on Windows. May be it just won't work with Visual Studio.